# Do we have a single API for searching a file in google services like GMail, Google Drive, Google Docs, etc...?

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail-api, google-docs-api

I am building an application which searches for files in gmail, google drive, google docs. I got one solution to search the files but it makes different http api calls to all these different services. Instead, do we have a single api to search in all google products like gmail, gdrive, gdocs, etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Google has separate APIs for different services. In fact, you can see the list [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).